# this.setState not a function rails

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

```
componentDidMount() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/tweets",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data){
            //$('#tweetsList').append(data);
            this.setState({tweetsList: data});
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

the above block of code gives me a this.setState function not found error. I am trying to render json from my Tweets controller to my main.jsx file.

Comment: the context of this changes in the ajax call. You need to reference the original context. Writing answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context of `this` changes in the ajax call. `this` no longer refers to your component. You need to reference the original context.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const self = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/tweets",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data){
            //$('#tweetsList').append(data);
            self.setState({tweetsList: data});
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The page renders without any error. However, no data is rendered from the controller.

Comment: is that because you have commented out `$('#tweetList').append(data)`?

Comment: Nope. it's unrelated. My index method in the tweets controller looks as follows: def index
  @tweets = Tweet.all
  render json: Tweet.all
 end

Comment: first of all you're making two calls to `Tweet.all`. Just call it once: `render json: @tweet`. secondly print your @tweets. Maybe nothing is being returned from your database: `p @tweets`

Comment: I had the first @tweets if in case I want to list in my index view. The render call is actually the one I am interested in. I have tweets in the database (I can see them in my rails console).

Comment: Never mind. I had a stupid typo in my tweet js file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `this` in your success callback function refers to that function and therefore doesn't have any `setState` method. You can pass context to jQuery ajax call like this:

`$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/tweets",
        dataType: "json",
        context: this,
        success: function (data){
            //$('#tweetsList').append(data);
            this.setState({tweetsList: data});
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });`

See [jQuery ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) about context property for more info.

Comment: Thanks. The page renders without any error. However, no data is rendered from the controller.